# Guaranteed Processing - How to implement between two message based services?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, messaging

I am developing an application consisting of 2 services. The services are message based and communicate over Apache Kafka (1 Topic for service 1 -> service 2, another Topic for service 2 -> service 1).

Workflow:

1. Service 1 is connected to a database where it reads messages and sends them to service 2.
2. In service 2 the messages get enriched with additional information and then get sent back to service 1.
3. Service 1 saves the message back to the database.

Database <--> Service1 <-- Kafka --> Service2

The problem I am facing is: I have to make sure, that every message gets processed by service 2 and afterwards saved back to the database by service 1.

Example: Service 2 reads a message from Kafka and crashes. The message is lost.

**Is there a design pattern to achieve this by simpling changing/adding code? Or do I have to make architectural changes?**

Further information: The services are Spring Boot based and use Apache Camel / Google Protocol Buffer for messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to be absolutely clear that this is not the ideal use for kafka. Kafka is to be used in a pub sub architecture to provide loose coupling between producers and consumers. However in your case, the consumer processes the message and is supposed to return enriched message back to producer. If implementing from scratch, we could have implemented service2 as GRPC server that takes in message and returns the enriched message.

That being said, we can achieve what you want using kafka. We need to make sure that **we always acknowledge the message post the message is completely processed**. In context of service2 - when message is read from topic1 it would enrich it, persist to topic2 and only then acknowledge topic1 that message processing is complete.

So in your example - service2 reads message from kafka but goes down. Since the message was not acknowledged by service2, whenever it restarts - the message would be redelivered to it from kafka (since service2 never acknowledged it). However, it also means there is a chance of duplicate messages.

I would also suggest you to read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once) link. It gives you idea regarding **kafka transactions**. Your process can read from kafka, process it and write back to kafka in a single kafka transaction.

Comment: Hi @RishabhSharma, thanks for your response. I see the difficulties in this architecture, but I'm stuck to kafka for the moment. One question concerning the acknowlegdment of messages after them being processed: I read that kafka has a max amount of time its waiting for the acknowlegdment from the consumer. The processing of the messages can take serveral hours. I would think that this clashes with the max acknowlegdment  time. What are your thoughts?